# Pause a CCNode for a while time

Tags: cocos2d-x, scheduler, resume, pausing-execution

I want to Pause a CCNode for a while and after that resume it again.
when I use below code separately they work but when I want to resume this CCNode for a specific time when a button clicked it dose't work and occur an Assertion failed(that is:    pElement->paused == bPaused ).

```
//for pausing
this->pauseSchedulerAndActions();

//for resuming
this->resumeSchedulerAndActions();
```

I use below codes:

```
    #define TIME_FOR_RESUME  5.0f
    //function that called when my button click
    void myClass::myFunc(CCObject * pSender)
   {
    this->pauseSchedulerAndActions();
    this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(myClass::myResumeFunction), TIME_FOR_RESUME);
    }

   void myClass::myResumeFunction(float dt)
   {
    this->resumeSchedulerAndActions();
   }
```

Comment: it says : pause scheduler and actions .... I doubt the myResumeFunction will be called. What do you mean 'pause a CCNode' ? maybe this is not the right approach. What is in the node, etc ...

Comment: yes I insert a breakpoint in myResumeFunction but it dose't call and before that an Assertion failed. I mean pausing all the CCSprite and their scheduler's which seems it's not existing for a while and then resume all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this for pausing

```
this->unscheduleAllSelectors();
```

and this for resume

```
this->scheduleUpdate();
```

Comment: pause: pauseSchedulerAndActions();
  unscheduleAllSelectors(); resume:resumeSchedulerAndActions();
  scheduleUpdate();